# jQuery/AJAX form submit and result with no return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using an AJAX caller function to submit a login form as below, but the page it is directed to only responds when the user is found not to exist (working correctly), but when the login information is deemed correct, nothing is returned in alert or otherwise, what am I missing?

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#loginbutton").click(function() {
                var user = $("#user").val();
                var pass = $("#pass").val();
                var dataString = "user="+user+"&pass="+pass;
                if (user == "" || pass == "") {
                    alert("Please fill in all fields");
                }
                else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "login.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result) {
                            alert(result)
                        },
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/wp-db.php');

global $userdata;
global $wpdb; 

//get the posted values

$posted_username = 'matt-inovate';
$posted_password = 'Qazplm10';

$user_name = htmlspecialchars($posted_username,ENT_QUOTES);

$pass_word = wp_hash_password($posted_password);

$pass_md5 = md5($posted_password);

$pass = $pass_word;

$userinfo = get_userdatabylogin($user_name);

$passcheck = $userinfo->user_pass;

$conn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "fw1359063030", "75ozg3cMxM47kRlJEPdLl2iOPb3f4R") or mysql_error();
    $conn = mysql_select_db("db8760018806", $conn);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = '$posted_username'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error();
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($rows == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $passcheck."<br>";
        echo $row[2]."<br>";
        if ($passcheck == $row[2]) { echo "Login Success."; } else { echo "Login Failed."; }
    }
    else { echo "Could not find user."; }
?>
```

Comment: When you go to this page with your browser does the success return something?

Comment: Success only works to return if the username (at the moment) is incorrect. If the username is correct, it won't return alerts for Login Success or Login Failed after the password has been compared to the hash.

Comment: Also, you may want to phase out the `mysql_*` series of functions, it is removed from PHP 7 and deprecated starting from 5.5. It's also unsafe to use in general.

Comment: If you'd like to try here is the page http://www.weddingindustryinsider.com/VAWEAPP/index.php click the bar icon on the top left, and go to login, then use 'matt-inovate' for login and 'Qazplm10' for correct password.

Comment: Will do regarding     mysql_* , guess I just haven't gotten used to mysqli yet

Comment: If I were you, I would use `PDO`, it is much more straight-forward. I find `mysqli_` a pain.

Comment: If you look in your console, you will see your login.php page is having a Internal Server Error 500. No matter what goes into username and password, it all generates that error for me.

Comment: not a good idea to post the username and password here.

Comment: It's a temp login so no big deal. Question though, with Rasclatt's help I was able to fix the code to make the ajax success work, but how do i (with a correct result) make it redirect the page? All I get now is just the alert, I want to make it redirect after the alert.